# More than sqrt(2)*AC after the rectifier. Why?

Tags: transformer, rectifier, water

I encountered the following issue: supplying **one working PCB with two different transformers** (same model), the voltages on the PCB are different *(higher!)*, even though the output voltages of the transformers are right at the first glance. I'm wondering why is this happening at one of the bridge rectifiers:

[image]

**PS: the "faulty" transformer was slightly splashed with water and a short was heard from the equipment *(not sure if the short happened in the transformer)*; the voltages are fine though**

Comment: A lot depends on exactly how the AC voltage was measured - most DVM with AC scale just use a peak detector circuit, scaled by 1.414, because they assume zero DC offset and a clean sinewave signal. Those assumptions are not valid if the signal has DC offset or has harmonic distortion or a non-sinusoidal waveform (different crest factor, so RMS voltage is not 1.414xVpp). Would be worth adding what make/model DMM you are using, and if you have an oscilloscope available and can make the measurements safely, would be helpful to see what the waveform actually looks like.

Comment: @MarkU I also tought about the wave forms but sadly I don't have an oscilloscope at hand now. My multimeter is not TRMS.